# Redirect FILE * stdout to string in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to execute some function of C in C++. The function takes FILE * as argument:

```
void getInfo(FILE* buff, int secondArgument);
```

You can make it to print to stdout:

```
getInfo(stdout, 1);
// the function prints results into stdout, results for each value secondArgument
```

But how to make this function to print to stream or stringstream in c++, process the results? I want to capture what the function prints, into a string, and do some processing on the resulting string.

I try something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  getInfo(stdout, i);
  // but dont want print to stdout. I want capture for each i, the ouput to some string
  // or array of strings for each i.
}
```

Comment: You can associate a `FILE*` to a pipe, either by creating a pipe special file (on Windows, this is called a named pipe) and using its path with `fopen`, or via an OS-specific fd-to-`FILE*` conversion.  Then read from the output end of the pipe into your string.  On Linux you also have the option of creating a temporary file on a tmpfs mount, which is "a filesystem", but operates at the speed of RAM without touching disk.

Comment: But how? Any example on Linux?

Comment: Which option are you interested in?  Named pipe?  Anonymous pipe?  Or tmpfs file?

Comment: Best one in linux. This function getInfo(stdout, secondArgument); is executed many times in a loop for different value of secondArgument. I update question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linux, your best bet is anonymous pipe.

First, create a pipe:

```
int redirectPipe[2];
pipe(redirectPipe)
```

Then, open the file descriptor returned to us via pipe(2) using fdopen:

```
FILE* inHandle = fdopen(redirectPipe[0], "w");
FILE* outHandle = fdopen(redirectPipe[1], "r");
```

Call the function:

```
getInfo(inHandle, someValue);
```

Then, read using `outHandle` as if it's a regular file.

One thing to be careful: Pipes have fixed buffer size and if there is a possibility for getInfo function to fill the buffer, you'll have a deadlock.

To prevent the deadlock, you can either call `getInfo` from another thread, or increase pipe buffer size using `fcntl` and `F_SETPIPE_SZ`. Or better, as Ben Voigt mentioned in the comments, create a temp file.

Note: I was specific to *nix since OP mentioned he/she wanted the "best one in linux"